# Why the value change back to original value after findIndex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I am trying to update the value of the item.
the item data is coming from redux store and is shown on the page

Here is the data[image]

So I will now try to edit the value of the item.
after edit then save i console log out the value. Here is the code

```
const save = async (key) => {
  try {
    const row = await this.formRef.current.validateFields();
    // ============================ i change here ===============
    const newData = [...data];
    console.log(newData)
    const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);
    // ============================ ===============
    console.log(index)
    console.log(newData)
    console.log(newData[index])
    // this.props.updateItem(newData[index])
    // ============================ ===============
    if (index > -1) {
      const item = newData[index];
      newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
      this.setState({
        data: newData,
        editingKey: "",
      });
    } else {
      newData.push(row);
      this.setState({
        data: newData,
        editingKey: "",
      });
    }
  } catch (errInfo) {
    console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
  }
};
```

As you can see there are many console.log.
For me to update the item i need to find the index of the item i updated.
There you can see there is a line of code that find the index.

when i console.log the newdata. The data is updated but
When i console log (newData[index]) the values are changed back to the old one.

here is the image

[image]

Can someone tell me why the values are changed back to the old one.
and how can i correct this behaviour

Comment: This is probably to do with the browser console, it shows the value of the logged object at the time you expand the array not at the time it was logged.

Comment: @Titus
When I open the comment out line this.props.updateItem(newItem[index])

and console.log from the prop component

the data sent is the old one not the new one

Comment: Do you mean the `console.log(newData[index])` statement. At that point, `newData[index]` hasn't been changed yet, it is changed when `newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row })` is executed.